# How to debug "company backend" initialization problems?

Tags: company-mode, debugging, use-package

I am getting error messages initializing some company backend packages, but messages only appear in the `*Messages*` buffer, like:

```
Company backend 'company-web' could not be initialized:
Symbol's function definition is void: company-web
Company backend 'company-quickhelp' could not be initialized:
Symbol's function definition is void: company-quickhelp
Company backend 'company-php' could not be initialized:
Symbol's function definition is void: company-php
```

I can't find a way to spot the problem, my current `.emacs` relevant code is:

```
(use-package company-web)
(use-package company-quickhelp)
(use-package company-php)
(use-package company
  :bind (("C-?" . company-complete))
  :config
  (global-company-mode t)
  (add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-php)
  (add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-quickhelp)
  (add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-web)
  )
```

Notes

- Using [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package))
- `--debug-init` doesn't show anything

**Update**: Fixed `company-php` and `company-web` but not `company-quickhelp`

Fix `company-php` and `company-web`:

```
(use-package company-web
  :config
  (require 'company-web-html))
(use-package company
  :bind (("C-?" . company-complete))
  :config
  (global-company-mode t)
  (add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-web-html) ;; changed from company-web
  (add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-ac-php-backend)
  )
```

`company-quickhelp` still shows the error in `*Messages*` with:

```
(use-package company-quickhelp
  :config
  (company-quickhelp-mode 1))
```

Comment: try `(use-package company-web :ensure t)`. And add your backends this way `(add-to-list 'company-backends '(company-php company-quickhelp company-php))`. And add your backends for the major mode you need them for and not in your `company` config.

Comment: @bertfred Question updated, the problem with `company-web` was the way of adding it to the backend list, just `company-quickhelp` isn't working now. (I have added other backends the same way and works fine)

Comment: What error are you getting with `company-quickhelp` ? 
Also, you'd have to place `company-quickhelp` either inside `company`s config or after `company`s use-package decleration.

Comment: Also, it's better to create a local `company-backends` variable for each `major-mode` and add company backends to that variable.